# Power series converging to differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

They give  $\;a>1\,,\;b>0\;$ , and also the existence of $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ such that $\;b^N<a\;$ .

We need to prove that the series

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(b^nx)}{a^n}$$

converges to a function that is differentiable $\;N\;$ times in $\;(0,1)\;$ .

This is my work so far: we have that for *any* $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ :

$$\left|\frac{\sin(b^nx)}{a^n}\right|\le\frac1{a^n}\implies \;\text{since}\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a^n}$$

converges (even absolutely) because of $\;|a^{-1}|<1\;$, Wierstrass M-test gives that our series converges uniformly on $\;\Bbb R\;$ and, for each real $\;x\;,\;\;f(x)$ also converges absolutely.

Since we can differentiate elementwise when we're into the convergence interval, we have that for all reals

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac ba\right)^n\cos(b^nx)$$

...and problems begin here: how can I be sure the above converges? Even if $\;x\in (0,1)\;$ , as the problem asks, I can't assure the above converges *unless* $\;\frac ba<1\;$, which could allow me to use W-M test again. But I only know that there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;\;\;\;\frac{b^n}a<1\;$ , not to mention higher order derivatives.

I feel something basic is sliding from me but I can't tell what. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You only want to differentiate $k$ times for $k\leqslant N$. That gives you a factor of $\left(\frac{b^k}{a}\right)^n$. Now you need to see that $\frac{b^k}{a} < 1$ for $k\leqslant N$. Hmm.

Comment: Thanks you sir, @DanielFischer . Yet how is $\;f'(x)\;$ convergent? Is perhaps good to show inductively that $\;\frac{b^k}a<1\;$ for $\;k\le N\;$ ?

Comment: You don't need induction for that. Distinguish two cases, $0 < b \leqslant 1$, and $1 < b$.